# A pretty simple Rock, Paper, Scissor game on C++

Tags: c++, beginner

I've decided to learn more about C++ with the time that I have right now through Udemy courses. To test out the stuff that I've learned up until now, I decided to try and code with some of the knowledge I've gained. I wanted try out object oriented features since I've been doing stuff through procedural programming instead. This is just a simple program utilising a few bits of OOP. I'm not sure if my use of it is appropriate (seeing as it is very minimal in use throughout the program). I would love some feedback and some tips to improve. Please keep feedback simple since I'm new to programming in general, and I don't know all of the technical jargon. Thanks.

```
// SIMPLE ROCK PAPER SCISSOR GAME w/ some OOP features
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Player {      //stores player/enemy points
private:
    int score;
public:
    int getScore() {
        return score;
    }
    
    void incrementScore() {
        score++;
    }
    //constructor
    Player(int points);
};

//constructor
Player::Player(int points)
    : score {points} {
}

int convertToInt(string pChoice) {      //converts player input into integers
    if (pChoice == "Rock" || pChoice == "rock") {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (pChoice == "Paper" || pChoice == "paper") {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (pChoice == "Scissor" || pChoice == "scissor") {
        return 2;
    }
    
    return 0;
}

bool inputValidation(const vector <string> choices, string pChoice) {      //validates player input
    bool boolean {};
    for (const string choice : choices) {     //checks vector that contains a list of all possible options
        if (choice == pChoice) {        
            boolean = true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            boolean = false;
        }
    }
    return boolean;
}

void printEnemyChoice(unsigned int &enemyRand, string &enemyChoice) {   //prints enemy choice
//remember that 0, 1 and 2 correspond to rock, paper and scissor respectively
    switch (enemyRand) {
        case 0: {
            enemyChoice = "Rock";
            cout << "Enemy picked: " << enemyChoice << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            enemyChoice = "Paper";
            cout << "Enemy picked: " << enemyChoice << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            enemyChoice = "Scissors";
            cout << "Enemy picked: " << enemyChoice << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void checkResult(Player &playerScore, Player &enemyScore, unsigned int &playerIChoice, unsigned int &enemyRand) {   //determines the winner
/* a 2D array is used to compared playerIChoice (the player's choice) and the enemy's choice (randomly generated)
 * 0 represents draw
 * 1 represents player's win
 * 2 represents enemy's win
 * remember that 0, 1, 2 is also Rock, Paper and Scissor respectively.. bit confusing. Hope theres a better way to name this properly.
 * for eg. if playerIChoice = 2 (Scissors) and enemyRand = 1 (Paper), this points to "1" on the 2D array (3rd row, column 2)
 * since it points to a "1", therefore the player wins (Scissors beats Paper). 
 * 1 is assigned to result, which is used in a switch statement to print out the winner on case 1 and increments the playerScore.score attribute.
 */ 

    int resultArray[3][3] {
        {0, 2, 1},  
        {1, 0, 2},
        {2, 1, 0}
    };
        
    int result = resultArray[playerIChoice][enemyRand];
    switch (result) {
        case 0: {
            cout << "Result is: Draw" << endl;
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            cout << "Result is: You win!" << endl;
            playerScore.incrementScore();
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            cout << "Result is: You lose!" << endl;
            enemyScore.incrementScore();
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    Player playerScore {0};
    Player enemyScore {0};
    bool gameLoop {true};
    const vector <string> choices {"Rock", "rock", "Paper", "paper", "Scissor", "scissor", "Q", "q"};
    string playerChoice {};
    string enemyChoice {};
    unsigned int playerIChoice {};
    unsigned int enemyRand {};
    
    cout << "======================================" << endl;
    cout << "Rock, Paper, Scissor! - CLI w/ Objects" << endl;
    cout << "======================================" << endl;
    
    while (gameLoop) {
        cout << "\nChoose rock, paper, or scissor: " << endl;
        cout << "Press Q to quit the game." << endl;
        cin >> playerChoice;
        
        if (playerChoice == "Q" || playerChoice == "q") {
            cout << "Thanks for playing." << endl;
            gameLoop = false;
            break;
        }
        
        if (inputValidation(choices, playerChoice) == false) {      //passes vector with valid input and player's input to compare
            cout << "Invalid input, try again!" << endl;
            continue;
        }
        
        cout << "You picked: " << playerChoice << endl;
        playerIChoice = convertToInt(playerChoice);         //converts valid input into integers to compare with enemy's choice
        
        srand (time(NULL));
        enemyRand = rand() % 3;     //generates random number from 0-2
        
        printEnemyChoice(enemyRand, enemyChoice);
        checkResult(playerScore, enemyScore, playerIChoice, enemyRand);
        
        cout << "\nYour score is: " << playerScore.getScore() << endl;
        cout << "Enemy score is: " << enemyScore.getScore() << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I will focus mostly on the object oriented part.

So, to make the code more *object oriented*, you need more objects. Free methods (i.e. methods that are not part of any class) with a lot of mutable arguments (references to types) are usually a sign that there is an object missing, since we are changing *states* of other objects.

Let's start by removing the entire logic in the main method. For this, we will create an object "RockScissorPaper", which has a constructor and a play-method, and a sub-set of the variables defined in your main.

```
class RockPaperScissors
{
public:
    RockPaperScissors();
    void play();

private:
    Player playerScore_ {0}; // suffixing with "_" to mark that these are member variables
    Player enemyScore_ {0};
    const vector <string> choices_ {"Rock", "rock", "Paper", "paper", "Scissor", "scissor", "Q", "q"};
};
```

The constructor of RockPaperScissors can be

```
RockPaperScissors::RockPaperScissors() : 
{
    cout << "======================================" << endl;
    cout << "Rock, Paper, Scissor! - CLI w/ Objects" << endl;
    cout << "======================================" << endl;
};
```

.

Now we can put the logic into the play-method. I will move each variable to right before it is used (good practice):

```
RockPaperScissors::play()
{
  bool gameLoop{true};
  while (gameLoop) {
    cout << "\nChoose rock, paper, or scissor: " << endl;
    cout << "Press Q to quit the game." << endl;
    string playerChoice {};
    cin >> playerChoice;
    
    if (playerChoice == "Q" || playerChoice == "q") {
        cout << "Thanks for playing." << endl;
        gameLoop = false;
        break;
    }
    
    if (inputValidation(choices_, playerChoice) == false) {      //passes vector with valid input and player's input to compare
        cout << "Invalid input, try again!" << endl;
        continue;
    }
    
    cout << "You picked: " << playerChoice << endl;
    unsigned int playerIChoice = convertToInt(playerChoice);         //converts valid input into integers to compare with enemy's choice
    
    srand (time(NULL));
    unsigned int enemyRand = rand() % 3;     //generates random number from 0-2
    
    string enemyChoice {};
    printEnemyChoice(enemyRand, enemyChoice);
    checkResult(playerScore_, enemyScore_, playerIChoice, enemyRand);
    
    cout << "\nYour score is: " << playerScore_.getScore() << endl;
    cout << "Enemy score is: " << enemyScore_.getScore() << endl;
  }
}
```

Now we can move `inputValidation`, and `checkResult` as *private* methods of RockPaperScissors. `printEnemyChoice` and `convertToInt` do not rely on any private members of RockPaperScissors, but are relying on internal logic of the class. I will thus put them there as well, but as *static methods* of the class.

```
class RockPaperScissors
    {
    public:
        RockPaperScissors();
        void play();
    
    private:
        void checkResult(unsigned int &playerIChoice, unsigned int &enemyRand);
        bool inputValidation(string pChoice);

        static void printEnemyChoice(unsigned int &enemyRand, string &enemyChoice);    
        static int convertToInt(string pChoice);

        Player playerScore_ {0}; // suffixing with "_" to mark that these are member variables
        Player enemyScore_ {0};
        const vector <string> choices_ {"Rock", "rock", "Paper", "paper", "Scissor", "scissor", "Q", "q"};
    };
```

Note that the member methods have less arguments. I also added the last function *convertToInt* as a *static method* of RockPaperScissors, since it relies on internal logic of the class. A static method cannot access the state variables, which is fine, since "convertToInt" does not do that.

The play method is now instead

```
RockPaperScissors::play()
{
  bool gameLoop{true};
  while (gameLoop) {
    cout << "\nChoose rock, paper, or scissor: " << endl;
    cout << "Press Q to quit the game." << endl;
    string playerChoice {};
    cin >> playerChoice;
    
    if (playerChoice == "Q" || playerChoice == "q") {
        cout << "Thanks for playing." << endl;
        gameLoop = false;
        break;
    }
    
    if (inputValidation(playerChoice) == false) {      //passes vector with valid input and player's input to compare
        cout << "Invalid input, try again!" << endl;
        continue;
    }
    
    cout << "You picked: " << playerChoice << endl;
    unsigned int playerIChoice = convertToInt(playerChoice);         //converts valid input into integers to compare with enemy's choice
    
    srand (time(NULL));
    unsigned int enemyRand = rand() % 3;     //generates random number from 0-2
    
    string enemyChoice {};
    printEnemyChoice(enemyRand, enemyChoice);
    checkResult(playerIChoice, enemyRand);
    
    cout << "\nYour score is: " << playerScore_.getScore() << endl;
    cout << "Enemy score is: " << enemyScore_.getScore() << endl;
  }
}
```

The main method now looks like:

```
int main() {
    RockPaperScissors rps{};
    rps.play();
    return 0;
}
```

Now you have one *main* game class, and a person class. A next step could be to refactor "Rock","Paper","Scissors"-logic to a separate class - so that the main class does not need to have the responsibility of this. It's good practice to create as small classes as possible, each of them having a specific goal.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the feedback I needed. By "Rock, Paper, Scissors logic" are you referring to the checkResults() method?

Comment: @novachrono, I actually meant `convertToInt`, since it has logic for how to convert user input to an int. But I think `checkResults` can also be made an object with the resposibility check the scores. If you are just playing around with OOP, you can make everything an object. Just try to assign it a specific responsibility and figure out its dependencies to other objects.

Answer (score 7):

**General Observations**
The game could have more than 2 players, you might want to use a container class to store the players. If this is a single player against the computer, it might be better if `enemy` was renamed to computer.

**Avoid `using namespace std;`**
If you are coding professionally you probably should get out of the habit of using the `using namespace std;` statement. The code will more clearly define where `cout` and other identifiers are coming from (`std::cin`, `std::cout`). As you start using namespaces in your code it is better to identify where each function comes from because there may be function name collisions from different namespaces. The identifier`cout` you may override within your own classes, and you may override the operator `<<` in your own classes as well. This [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) discusses this in more detail.

**Magic Numbers - Make the Code as Self Documenting as Possible**
There are Magic Numbers in the `convertToInt()` function (0, 1, 2), it might be better to use an [ENUM](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum) or create symbolic constants for them to make the code more readble and easier to maintain. These numbers may be used in many places and being able to change them by editing only one line makes maintenance easier. In this case an ENUM is probably better.

Numeric constants in code are sometimes referred to as [Magic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)), because there is no obvious meaning for them. There is a discussion of this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad).

It is better to have self documenting code using enums or symbolic constants, because it makes the code easier to read and maintain. Using comments is good where necessary, but they need to be maintained as well as the code, so it is better to write self documenting code.

If you use an [std::map<>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) the function `convertToInt()` isn't necessary, table look up is generally faster than logic, and easier to maintain or expand:

```
#include <map>
using objectType = enum {ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS};
using objectTypeMap = std::map<std::string, objectType >;


objectTypeMap initChoices()
{
    std::map<std::string, objectType > choices;
    choices.insert({"Rock", ROCK});
    choices.insert({"rock", ROCK});
    choices.insert({"Paper", PAPER});
    choices.insert({"Paper", PAPER});
    choices.insert({"Scissors", SCISSORS});
    choices.insert({"scissors", SCISSORS});

    return choices;
}
```

In main():

```
    ...
    string playerChoice {};
    string enemyChoice {};
    objectType playerIChoice {};
    objectTypeMap stringConverter = initChoices();

    ...
        playerIChoice = stringConverter[playerChoice];         //converts valid input into integers to compare with enemy's choice
    ...
```